# Unable to fetch data to dashboard using netflix hystrix turbine

Tags: hystrix, spring-cloud-netflix, turbine

We are using netflix turbine to fetch data from cluster and display on hystrix dashboard.

I have one cluster called **PROD** with only one node(**192.168.33.17**) in which java application (hystrix) is running on port 8989.

We have turbine node where we have following configuration:

config.properties file:

```
turbine.aggregator.clusterConfig=PROD
turbine.instanceUrlSuffix.PROD=/hystrix.stream
turbine.ConfigPropertyBasedDiscovery.PROD.instances=192.168.33.17:8989/hystrix-examples-webapp
InstanceDiscovery.impl=com.netflix.turbine.discovery.ConfigPropertyBasedDiscovery
```

and placing config.properties file specified using a JVM property such as
    java -Darchaius.configurationSource.additionalUrls=file:///home/vagrant/config.properties -jar start.jar

When we are directly accessing node data using

```
curl http://192.168.33.17:8989/hystrix-examples-webapp/hystrix.stream
```

then response is proper and we are able to see on the dashboard.

But when we doing the same using turbine we can't see any response on dashboard, although we are getting ping response for

```
 curl http://192.168.33.13:8080/turbine/turbine.stream
```

response    :ping

with turbine log:

```
2016-08-22 17:40:11 INFO  com.netflix.turbine.discovery.InstanceObservable$1:260 [InstanceObservable$1] [run]: Retrieved hosts from InstanceDiscovery: 1
2016-08-22 17:40:11 INFO  com.netflix.turbine.discovery.InstanceObservable$1:272 [InstanceObservable$1] [run]: Found hosts that have been previously terminated: 0
2016-08-22 17:40:11 INFO  com.netflix.turbine.discovery.InstanceObservable$1:289 [InstanceObservable$1] [run]: Hosts up:1, hosts down: 0
2016-08-22 17:41:11 INFO  com.netflix.turbine.discovery.InstanceObservable$1:260 [InstanceObservable$1] [run]: Retrieved hosts from InstanceDiscovery: 1
2016-08-22 17:41:11 INFO  com.netflix.turbine.discovery.InstanceObservable$1:272 [InstanceObservable$1] [run]: Found hosts that have been previously terminated: 0
2016-08-22 17:41:11 INFO  com.netflix.turbine.discovery.InstanceObservable$1:289 [InstanceObservable$1] [run]: Hosts up:1, hosts down: 0
2016-08-22 17:42:11 INFO  com.netflix.turbine.discovery.InstanceObservable$1:260 [InstanceObservable$1] [run]: Retrieved hosts from InstanceDiscovery: 1
2016-08-22 17:42:11 INFO  com.netflix.turbine.discovery.InstanceObservable$1:272 [InstanceObservable$1] [run]: Found hosts that have been previously terminated: 0
2016-08-22 17:42:11 INFO  com.netflix.turbine.discovery.InstanceObservable$1:289 [InstanceObservable$1] [run]: Hosts up:1, hosts down: 0
2016-08-22 17:43:11 INFO  com.netflix.turbine.discovery.InstanceObservable$1:260 [InstanceObservable$1] [run]: Retrieved hosts from InstanceDiscovery: 1
2016-08-22 17:43:11 INFO  com.netflix.turbine.discovery.InstanceObservable$1:272 [InstanceObservable$1] [run]: Found hosts that have been previously terminated: 0
2016-08-22 17:43:11 INFO  com.netflix.turbine.discovery.InstanceObservable$1:289 [InstanceObservable$1] [run]: Hosts up:1, hosts down: 0
2016-08-22 17:44:11 INFO  com.netflix.turbine.discovery.InstanceObservable$1:260 [InstanceObservable$1] [run]: Retrieved hosts from InstanceDiscovery: 1
2016-08-22 17:44:11 INFO  com.netflix.turbine.discovery.InstanceObservable$1:272 [InstanceObservable$1] [run]: Found hosts that have been previously terminated: 0
2016-08-22 17:44:11 INFO  com.netflix.turbine.discovery.InstanceObservable$1:289 [InstanceObservable$1] [run]: Hosts up:1, hosts down: 0
20
```

So, are we missing any configuration ?

Comment: The thing with Hystrix is that is starts showing metric data in stream only when the first flow hit reaches the command in your code. So after just starting the hystrix enabled app and checking its stream you would just see pings and no data because there is none.
I haven't tried your code but it looks okie with the kind of setup you mentioned but almost everyone misses this point about hystrix usage.

Comment: thanks @Nazgul, will checkout this.